# Json Representation of JIRA projects , users , groups etc

Tags: git, jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to automate the JIRA administration by having all the configuration done through json files in version control , and when , for example someone want to make a change to his project , he/she can just create a pull request for that change by editing the relevant json file for that and I will just either merge it and push it to REST api , or suggest a change.

I need to know how can I grab all the current configuration as Json files so that I can setup this workflow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the important top-level entities in JIRA also have a `/meta` endpoint which explains the required and optional fields and what kind of data should be entered there. Check out the documentation [here](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/server/).

Alternatively, if they don't have that endpoint just expand the endpoint you need and they have a **Schema** heading where you can see the metadata.

Comment: hi , thanks. actually i want to see all the existing configuration as json files , once i get those , then i can use a python library to do the configuration onward.

Comment: What do you mean by "configuration"? Everything that the JIRA Rest API accepts is outlined in those docs